# Как сделать так, чтобы сайт по https общался с сервером

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, express, backend

Я разработал сайт и сервер: с
— сайт на хостинге с SSL сертификатом (работает по https);
— сервер запустил сервер на VPS хостинге с помощью Docker. Сервер слушает 443 порт по https.

Когда я делаю запросы с сайта к данному серверу, возникает ошибка:

```
POST https://... net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

В поддержке мне сказали:

> Сертификат Let’s Encrypt нельзя выпустить на ip, можно поставить самоподписной сертификат, но при подключении будет соответствующее предупреждение, поэтому запросы со стороны другого сайта будут отклоняться, пока не перейти на ресурс и не принять риск. Более консистным решением будет направление какого-либо домена на впс, выпуск сертификата на него, корректировка настроек на исходном сайте - АДРЕС САЙТА - чтобы запросы шли к этому домену по https.

Я не понял, что мне предлагает поддержка.

Объясните, пожалуйста, по шагам, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы сайт и сервер общались по https.

Comment: А зачем вы на сайт ходите по IP?

Comment: на сайт захожу по домену, у сервера нет домена, есть только ip

Comment: Заведите серверу домен.